# Laravel Eloquent - Get Relationship Elements only where "where" condition in "with" is true

Tags: laravel, eloquent, null, where-clause

I have the model `student`, `courses` and `group`. `student` and `group` are related through `courses` in a many to many relationship. `group` has a field called `year`.
I'm trying to get all the students that have a group related to them in which the group has the field year equals to a variable `$year`. The initial query works great, but I also need that the student model returns with the group that equals the `$year` value. There can be only one group in the same year associated to that student. Here is the query that I have right now.

```
Student::whereHas('courses.group', function ($query) use ($year) {
            return $query->where('year', '=', $year);
        })->where('active', '=', '1')->with(['courses.group' => function ($query) use ($year){
            $query->where('year', '=', $year);
        }])->get()
```

This query works to an extend, it returns only the students that have a group related to them with the group having the value of `$year`, it also returns the relations of courses that the student has, the problem is that it returns all the relations, and in those relations it only returns the groups that have the same year as `$year`. I need those `courses` relationships that return "null" to not be there. Any idea how can i solve this?, thanks ;)

Here's an example:
This is a student model

[image: student model]

It returns with the `courses` relation and the `groups` relation.

[image: student relations]

Comment: Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: Hi, Cornel :) , those two `courses` do have a group related to them, it returns null in one of them because that group has a value different to the one defined in $year, idk if i could use whereDoesntHave, after the last `with` in order to get rid of one of the ``courses`. I will give it a shot. Thnx

Comment: I see in one sub-query function closure you `return` and in the other you don't.  I don't think you need to return. (Just a side comment.  This will solve nothing - sorry.)

Comment: Also, not solving your issue - this is a great package. https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Comment: Thanks Tarek, i removed the other `return` statement just in case haha.

Comment: Omg. I am too tired. I completely misread what you need here. Let me think and get back to you.

Comment: Try to remove the `with` altogether. The thing is that it is only returning the students that have the course with the group in that year but then, with `with` you load all the groups for all the courses the Student is enrolled in and that requires to load all the courses

Comment: I tried to get the relation after the fact, but i cannot use a conditional on them. Example `$user->courses->group` will return every course it has related to it, i need the $user to return only with the course that has the group with the year that i'm looking for. That's why I used the `with`

Comment: I don;t think you would need the second where condition inside the `with` callback. But, that's not the answer you are looking for. If I may ask, how have you defined the relationships in the models; would you share in the question? Is `Course` a pure pivot model? Maybe I am overthinking, but, if it's a `many to many` between `student` and `group` through a `courses` table as a pivot, I don't understand the existence of a `null` relationship.

Comment: Hi user3532758, the course is a pivot table that has an aditional field. The relation in the model `student` and `group` is `many to many` toward the course model. It returns null on the relation because of the `where` that i have set up. The objective of that where is to get only the group that matchs the criteria, so i can have that information avaliable along with the user. Maybe i'm aproaching this query from the wrong side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up doing multiple joins, I dont know if it is less efficient than doing it with Eloquent methods. Here is the query if someone is interested.

```
Student::whereHas('courses.group')->where('active', '=', '1')
            ->join('courses', 'courses.id_student','=','students.id_student')
            ->join('groups', 'groups.id_group', '=', 'courses.id_group')
            ->join('degree', 'degree.id_degree', 'groups.id_degree')
            ->where('year', '=', $year)->get()
```

If someone knows a better, cleaner o more efficient method I am all ears :)